# Creating incoming call overlay in iOS

Tags: ios, voip

I have already done this in Android, but I need to know if or how to do it in iOS. Having a somewhat definitive "no its not possible" will help me convince the powers that be.

The app I have is a VOIP app, although at this point all the incoming call handling is done via simple notifications. I know that if our app were in use (its more unified communications than simply voice so it may be active while not on a call) I could do this easily... its my app.

Its when the app is not in the foreground that I'm running stuck.

All the "how to do VOIP" examples use the voip socket to simply add a notification. While the APN notifications aren't terribly speedy, without the immediate feedback of a ringer, I can't justify putting in all the additional code (since we're not using SIP I'll have to write the socket layer myself in order to get the notifications slightly sooner).

Is it as simple as opening a custom URL which will launch my app and show the ringer (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://example.com/ringer/call-12321123"]];`)
? That would seem to not allow me to return the user to the app they were using before the ringing started.

Comment: Also calling `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:` does not seem to work when you app is in the background.

Comment: @rckoenes I was pretty sure that was the case. I'm beginning to think I'm out of luck.

Comment: Yay, I guess Apple does not allow this kind of level of interaction with the system.